# Find the center of mass of points

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, physics

I have N points. Each point has X and Y coordinates.

I need to find X and Y of center of mass this points. Can you give me an algorithm to accomplish this task?

Comment: What have you got so far ?

Comment: The question does not show particular research effort, but it is a useful hit for searches -> +1 (mainly to offset the -1)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Is there something wrong with just taking the weighted average by mass?

```
for each point n
{
    totalmass += n.mass
    totalx += n.x*n.mass
    totaly += n.y*n.mass
}
center = (totalx/totalmass,totaly/totalmass)
```

add additional dimensions as appropriate.

Comment: He can use the weighted mass **only if** the distribution of points is continuous or of equal density, otherwise he will have to resort to integrals to integrate over all space to find the density and appropriate mass. His question doesn't seem to ask or imply this, but I thought that I should point out in the general case, what I described is true. Refer to this: [Center of Mass](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/301/lectures/node102.html)

Comment: Can you elaborate on that a bit? Feel free to suggest an edit if necessary. I was under the impression that this would work for any possible collection of point masses.

Comment: @jrd1: But that solution only works in Euclidean geometry, and he didn't specify that either.

Comment: @honk, he did: x and y coordinates are Cartesian.

Comment: @Sconibulus, since for the general case involves different coordinate systems and taking into account different mass distributions, a full and complete solution would take a while to write since it would also require that an integration routine also be built on top of it. It's not impossible, but in actuality, rather involved - too much so for here.

Comment: @jrd1: He did specify that he has a discrete mass distribution, and my comment was laking a `:)` (I was referring to the metric). For a continuous mass distribution one just replaces the sums by integrals, e.g. `totalx = \int x dm` etc.

Comment: This solution only works if there is at least one point with a certain mass, otherwise you will get a division by zero exception.

Comment: @MichaelStauffer If you're trying to find center of mass of an item without mass... you're going to have a bad time.