# Calculate center of mass of surface from set of x, y coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, area, surface

I'm trying to determine the center of mass of a surface determined by a set of RANDOM non-equivalently spaced x, y points.
Here is a quick test set to show what I mean.

```
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def PolyArea(x, y):
    return 0.5*np.abs(np.dot(x, np.roll(y,1))-np.dot(y, np.roll(x,1)))

points = np.random.rand(30, 2)   # 30 random points in 2-D
hull = ConvexHull(points)

plt.plot(points[:,0], points[:,1])
for simplex in hull.simplices:
    plt.plot(points[simplex, 0], points[simplex, 1])

plt.plot(points[hull.vertices, 0], points[hull.vertices, 1], 'r--', lw=2)
plt.show()
```

From here we get:

```
x = points[hull.vertices, 0]
y = points[hull.vertices, 1]

surface_size = PolyArea(x, y)
```

I wish to determine the center of mass of the area from the points set (x, y), NOT the mean of the points. I know this to be calculated by a double integral of the surface (see: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/CenterOfMass.aspx), but I don't know how to implement it in Python.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801400/find-the-center-of-mass-of-points or http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/122020/

Comment: Thank you for your comment caramiriel, however, I am looking for the center of mass of non-equivalently spaced points ('x_n, y_n') and therefore, the related proposed posts are not sufficient. I am trying to implement the double integral method, however, I don't really know where to start in Python.

Comment: @LeonvandenHoven you don't need any integral unless you want to compute the center of mass of the surface your polygon encloses and the surface has varying intensity/mass. There's simple geometric formula to calculate the centroid of a polygon which you should be able to write easily in numpy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Centroid_of_a_polygon

Comment: If you need the center of mass of a non uniform intensity surface then my answer might actually be useful (with a couple of trivial changes)

Comment: If you have a surface mesh, it is really easy to do and you don't have to implement it yourself. https://github.com/mikedh/trimesh

Answer (score 1):

There's surely a much more elegant solution, but here's a quick and dirty, probably slow and overkill, image based one which kind of works.

```
import skimage.measure
import skimage.draw

GRIDW = 1000
GRIDH = 1000

img = np.zeros((GRIDW, GRIDH))

rr, cc = skimage.draw.polygon(x*GRIDW,y*GRIDH)
img[rr,cc] = 1

label = skimage.measure.label(img)
rprops = skimage.measure.regionprops(label)

print rprops[0].centroid / np.asarray([GRIDW, GRIDH])
```